# Tibco BusinessWorks 6 Parsing CSV File

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am trying to parse a CSV file as an input for my process.

I used the FilePoller to detect any changes, made in the .csv file. The poller is connected to the ParseData Activity which is referenced by the DataFormat Ressource, where I am defining the structure of my data. The output of ParseData is used in the RenderXML activity to create an xml string.

I am facing the issue, that I am not able to loop through each line in the CSV file to parse it to an XML document structure.

Do you have a resolution, how to implement this?

Please find the "Demo" process attached to this post.

[Link to Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dWi3.png)

Thank you in advance

Adrian

Answer (score 4):

1. Select both the RenderXml and WriteFile activities.  You can do that by clicking one, and then holding the Shift button while you click on the second.
2. Right-click over the selected activities, and select Create Group > Iterate.  This will create an Iterate Scope around the two selected activities.
3. Click on the Properties panel and select the output of the ParseData activity as the Variable List through which you would like to iterate.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are getting repeated element in Parse Data Output and these repeated element you want to map to render xml schema . Which is not allowed until and unless in schema you have element to which you want to map is of repeated type. If that element is of repeated type then map element from the right side to left side and select for each option. Then for every element in Parse data it will map to schema element.

Hope Your doubt get resolved.